# A question about typesetting a partitioned matrix

Tags: matrices

How one can create the following matrix?

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/submatrix-in-latex#8991

Comment: I have already seen this post. My question is different with this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two variants. I have to  use a `\raisebox` command, adjusted by trial and errors, because it seems `blockarray` environment, for some reason, is not centred on the mathaxis. The blockarray is not raised at all (`0pt`), but the optional arguments are here to fool LaTeX and make it believe the contents of the environment is slightly higher and less deep than it is really:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[ A =
    \begin{bmatrix}\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height + 1ex\relax][\dimexpr\depth- 2ex\relax]{$%
    \begin{blockarray}{c c c c}
        \begin{block}{[cc]cc}
        1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{cc[c] c}
        0 & 0 & {\,3\,} & 0\\
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{ccc[c]}
        0 & 0 & 0 & \,4\, \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} $}\!
    \end{bmatrix}
 \]


\[ A =
    \begin{bmatrix}\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height + 1ex\relax][\dimexpr\depth- 2ex\relax]{$%
     \begin{blockarray}{c c c c}
        \begin{block}{[cc\Right{]}{\hskip2.333em \raisebox{-0.4\height}[\height][\depth]{\rlap{\Large 0}}}cc}
        1 & 2 & \\
        3 & 4 &\\
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{cc[c] c}
       & & {\,3\,} & \\
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{ccc[c]}
           \BAmulticolumn{3}{c}{\raisebox{0.2\height}[\height][\depth]{\smash[t]{\llap{\Large 0}}\enspace }} & \,4\, \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} $}\!
    \end{bmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. For the benefit of any not-yet-expert-TeXnician readers of your answer, you may want to add a couple of explanatory sentences regarding the use of (a) the `\raisebox` "wrapper"  around the `blkarray` environment and (b)`{\,3\,}` instead of "just" `3`.

Comment: @Mico: Done, Mylord! Hope it's clear enough for no-experts.

Comment: there's a slight difference in the two results: the brackets around the "4" in the lower right corner are taller in the second version.  no doubt unintended.  (i haven't tested to determine why the difference, but i assume it has something to to with the height of the `\Large` zero.)  i'd be inclined to center at least the left large 0 horizontally; an `\llap` could be used for this.

Comment: @barbara beeton: my intention was to have the Large 0s symmetrical w.r.t. `[3]`. I smashed and lapped 'em. Is it more to your taste?

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
\begin{block}{[cc]cc}
1 & 2 & \cdot & \cdot\\
3 & 4 & \cdot & \cdot\\
\end{block}
\cdot & \cdot & [3] &\cdot\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & [4]\\
\end{blockarray}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

One can use `\circ` instead of `\cdot` . Nice package blkarray!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceMatrix}
  1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 4
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{2-2}]
  \SubMatrix[{3-3}{3-3}]
  \SubMatrix[{4-4}{4-4}]
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{4-4}][extra-height=2mm,xshift=3pt]
\end{NiceMatrix}\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]